# Did Cut and Paste of MySQL Database Files Between Servers and the Paste was Canceled

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, mysql, clipboard

I was moving MySQL Databases between two Windows Servers and the paste action was canceled. I noticed that the original Databases were partially transferred and there were some incomplete databases on the new Server.

I do have a backup and I generally prefer to do a dump/undump of databases, but I was curious about how Cut/Paste is supposed to work and if I can recover the database folders on the original server as they were prior to doing the Cut/Paste

Thanks in advance for any support you may provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you cancel a GUI move in Windows Explorer, the file in progress is deleted from the target and the source file is left alone. So if you fill in the missing files on either end with files from the other end you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That is what I thought, but after getting the database up and running on the target server, I am missing lots of tables. It is as if a bunch of tables that were originally there "vanished" during the cut/paste process. Very strange.

Comment: Not so strange. If you don't move the files in which the databases are stored, they won't be there when you start up the server.

Comment: I think I may have failed to explain myself. I did merge the files from the source server and the files that were already cut/pasted to the target server together on the target server. The items that are missing are from folders that were never even partially copied. Even if they were, they were merged... Something isn't right about this.